# в чем ошибка C++, C2064 fail

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> ogg{5,9,9,9,12,9};
auto a = find_if(ogg.begin(), ogg.end(), [=]()->bool {
    for (int i = 0; i < ogg.size(); ++i) {
        if (ogg[i] == 12)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
         false;
        }
        }});
cout << *a << endl;
ogg.clear();
system("pause");
```

Comment: Всегда умиляют конструкции вида `if (условие) return true; else return false;`

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то предикат получает в качестве аргумента элемент вектора...

```
auto a = find_if(ogg.begin(), ogg.end(),
                 [](int x) { return x == 12; }
                 );
```

Вот и все.

Но перед тем как писать

```
cout << *a << endl;
```

надо убедиться, что `a` не равно `ogg.end()`...

P.S. Но еще проще -

```
auto a = find(ogg.begin(), ogg.end(), 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  vector<int> ogg{5, 9, 9, 9, 122, 9};
  auto a = find_if(ogg.begin(), ogg.end(), [](int x) { 
    return x == 12; 
  });
  if(a == ogg.end()) 
    cout<<"NOT FOUND!";
  else
    cout << *a << endl;
  ogg.clear();
```

[Код](https://repl.it/repls/PleasedOutrageousAbilities)